# Sequence of Fibonnaci Numbers - Prolog

Tags: prolog, range, fibonacci

While attempting to learn Prolog I came across a good exercise which was to write a program that displays the Nth Fibonacci number. After some work I got it working and then decided to see if I could write a program that displays a range of Fibonacci numbers according to the input.

For instance the input:

```
?- fib_sequence(2,5,Output).
```

Gives the output:

```
?- Output = [1,1,2,3]
```

I am having difficulty, however, in finding a good starting point. This is what I have so far:

```
fib(0, 0).
fib(1, 1).
fib(N, F) :- X is N - 1, Y is N - 2, fib(X, A), fib(Y, B), F is A + B.

fib_sequence(A,B,R) :- fib(A,Y) , fib(B,Z).
```

I know I must assign a value to *R*, but I'm not sure how to assign multiple values. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that your `fib_sequence` cannot be done in a single predicate clause: you need at least two to keep things recursive - one to produce an empty list when `A` is greater than `B` (i.e. we've exhausted the range from A to B), and another one to prepend `X` from `fib(A,X)` to a list that you are building, increment `A` by `1`, and call `fib_sequence` recursively to produce the rest of the sequence.

The first predicate clause would look like this:

```
fib_sequence(A,B,[]) :- A > B.
```

The second predicate clause is a bit harder:

```
fib_sequence(A,B,[H|T]) :-
    A =< B                   /* Make sure A is less than or equal to B */
,   fib(A, H)                /* Produce the head value from fib(A,...) */
,   AA is A + 1              /* Produce A+1 */
,   fib_sequence(AA, B, T).  /* Produce the rest of the list */
```

Comment: It's not "cannot be done in a single predicate" but "cannot be done in a single clause" or "cannot be done in a single predicate clause". Also, not "The first predicate..." but "The first clause..." or "The first predicate clause...". Idem for "The second predicate".

Comment: I'm still new to Prolog so it may just be my inexperience causing this confusion but on your code: `fib_sequence(A,B,[H|T])` why are you trying to find the Head and Tail value of Output? Does it require to be fed the sequence of Fibonacci numbers to work? For instance I assumed when given input like `fib_sequence(2,5,Seq)` the program would then give `Seq = 1,1,2,3`.

Comment: So I think my question was misleading. When I said `?- fib_sequence(2,5,Output).` I meant the program, when run, would give you `?- Output = [1,1,2,3]`. My understanding is that Output can be any variable name i.e. Out, Seq, Range etc..  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Shrp91 That is precisely how I understood your question, and that is what my modification does ([demo](http://ideone.com/EFDQG2); see line 8 for the invocation with parameters 1, 5, and Output). The `[H|T]` are there to describe how the clause constructs the output list: `H` unifies with the `fib(A,H)`, while `T` unifies with the recursive call `fib_sequence(AA, B, T)`. You are not expected to feed anything into the output (unless you want to check if you've got the right sequence, as opposed to finding out the sequence from the two numbers).

Comment: Yes I apologize. I made incorrect assumptions when reading the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Prolog has some helper builtin to handle numeric sequences, then as an alternative to dasblinkenlight' answer, here is an idiomatic 'query':

```
fib_sequence(First, Last, Seq) :-
    findall(F, (between(First,Last,N), fib(N,F)), Seq).
```

note that it will not work out-of-the-box with your fib/2, because there is a bug: I've added a condition that avoid the endless loop you would experience trying to *backtrack* on fib/2 solutions:

```
fib(N, F) :- N > 1, % added sanity check
    X is N - 1, Y is N - 2, fib(X, A), fib(Y, B), F is A + B.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another approach. First, I redid `fib` a little so that it only recursively calls itself once instead of twice. To do this, I created a predicate that returns the prior the last two Fibonacci values instead of the last one:

```
fib(N, F) :-
    fib(N, F, _).
fib(N, F, F1) :-
    N > 2,
    N1 is N-1,
    fib(N1, F1, F0),
    F is F0 + F1.
fib(1, 1, 0).
fib(2, 1, 1).
```

For getting the sequence, I chose an algorithm with the Fibonacci calculation built-in so that it doesn't need to call `fib` O(n^2) times. It does, however, need to reverse the list when complete:

```
fib_sequence(A, B, FS) :-
    fib_seq_(A, B, FSR),
    reverse(FSR, FS).

fib_sequence_(A, B, []) :-
    A > B.
fib_sequence_(A, B, [F]) :-
    A =:= B,
    fib(A, F, _).
fib_sequence_(A, B, [F1,F0]) :-
    1 is B - A,
    fib(B, F1, F0).
fib_sequence_(A, B, [F2,F1,F0|FT] ) :-
    B > A,
    B1 is B - 1,
    fib_sequence_(A, B1, [F1,F0|FT]),
    F2 is F1 + F0.
```

Here's one more way, to do it without the reverse, but the reverse method above still appears to be a little faster in execution.

```
fib_sequence_dl(A, B, F) :-
    fib_sequence_dl_(A, B, F, [_,_|[]]).

fib_sequence_dl_(A, B, [], _) :-
    A > B, !.
fib_sequence_dl_(A, B, [F], _) :-
    A =:= B,
    fib(A, F, _), !.
fib_sequence_dl_(A, B, [F0,F1|T], [F0,F1|T]) :-
    1 is B - A,
    fib(B, F1, F0), !.
fib_sequence_dl_(A, B, F, [F1,F2|T]) :-
    A < B,
    B1 is B - 1,
    fib_sequence_dl_(A, B1, F, [F0,F1|[F2|T]]),
    F2 is F0 + F1.
```

Comment: I'm curious if there is a way to handle this without giving the Fibonacci sequence as an input?

Comment: @Shrp91 I'm not sure I understand the question. You don't need to feed the sequence to the predicate I am showing. For example, you enter `fib_sequence(3, 5, FS).` and it will instantiate `FS` with the sequence `[2,3,5]`, as your question requested.

Comment: Okay I apologize. I assumed since it was doing list manipulation that it required a list input. Thank you for the answer!